# Wix Toolset checking against .Net Version always evaluates to false

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I'm currently working on a bundle installer using Wix Toolset. The bundle contains three parts, one being an apropriate .Net Runtime.

I'm using the following query to get the currently installed .Net version:

```
<util:RegistrySearch
  Root="HKLM"
      
  Key="SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost"
  Value="Version"
  Win64="yes"    
  Variable="NetVersion"
/>
```

I then use the variable in the following ExePackage

```
<ExePackage SourceFile="D:\somepath\windowsdesktop-runtime-5.0.7-win-x64.exe"
  Vital="no"
  PerMachine="yes"
  InstallCondition="VersionNT64 AND NetVersion &lt; v5.0.7"/>
```

The second part of the statement: `NetVersion &lt; v5.0.7` always evaluates to false. It doesn't matter if I compare against, say version `4.0` or `7.0`, the installer wont show up in the process.

Maybe the problem has something to do with the installed dotnet version on my computer, which happen to be `6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5`.

I'm using an other query where I check against a more conservative version number (major.minor.build.revision) which works just fine.

Im using Wix toolset 3.11.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the "v" in the compare-expression?